# Geopandas save as KML doesn't include columns

Tags: python, geopandas, fiona

I tried to save the geopandas into KML.

Below are my code.

```
import fiona
fiona.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'
gp.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'
a = df_geom[['Geohash_8','Geohash_7','Final Action (Coverage)','geometry']].head(3)
a.to_file('test.kml',driver='KML')
```

When I open in Google Earth, the polygon does not displaying 'Final Action (Coverage)'.

Comment: As far as I understand, KML is not really supported by Fiona (see https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/97). Which means, even if you manually allow KML driver, that it does not handle everything correctly. It behaves weirdly, sometimes it exports what you would expect sometimes it does not (I couldn't find the pattern why). After several attempts I got all values correctly. Try adding other columns... not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solutions.

```
with open('./test.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(a.to_json())
# YOU NEED TO INSTALL ogrogr FROM https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/
import subprocess
subprocess.call("ogr2ogr -f KML ./test.kml ./test.json ",shell=True)
```